# Execution failed for task app:kaptDebugKotlin after updating firebase crashlytics, analytics and kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle, dagger

Thanks in advance, My problem is that after upgrading the Firebase Crashlytics, Analytics dependencies using firebase-bom:32.2.2 and kotlin version also (from 1.5.21 to 1.8.0), My project got broken and is unable to build, please help. Attached drive links of the build files both app lvl and project lvl and the file containing error detail with using stacktrace.

[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArrOKTOVTz9OMdZY_v8TgQKUUKDy3DCT/view?usp=sharing)
[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yLeXPv-GihhHDSadjsfS3yDBXv9fv28d/view?usp=sharing)
[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SC5oklAm7147SliOESwvhbDaFfH4Z0Wk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I tried clean and rebuild, also tried invalidate cache and restart then again rebuild but didn't worked. One thing also, this line kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.35"), if I replace kapt with annotationProcessor and then build then it gives error of unabe to resolve symbol 'DaggerAppComponent' inside my application class and then when I comment this (DaggerAppComponent)  and build, then it build apk successfully but when run that apk it crashes saying kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property activityInjector has not been initialized inside application class.

Answer (score 0):

Run your application with `./gradlew clean build` command to see what's exactly wrong with your code. You need to paste it into the Terminal in Android Studio.

If you are not familiar with building from Terminal , read [this](https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline)

Comment: Hi, @amirhosein ghobadi, thanks for the help but I have got it fixed already before your reply.

Answer (score 0):

after trying a lot of things and doing so much RnD, I found this line which saved me and build the code. Here it is,
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.4.2"
I Just added this line in the gradle build file and code build successfully, so basically it was asking for the jvm and here is the stack link on which I found this,

[Kotlin 1.7.10 with Dagger "A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180208/kotlin-1-7-10-with-dagger-a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotl)

Thank you